# How to create generic Service for Rest API Call using $http?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want generic service which i'll call from my controller. I want options to be passed dynamically.

For Example.

```
var app = angular.module('common', []);

app.factroy('APIService', ['$http', function($http){

    return {

        doApiCall: function(url, method, payload, headers){

        // I should make a call to server with the parameters passed from the controller.
        //

        }

    }

}]);


app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'common' , function($scope, common){

    // I want to call the doApiCall function provided by common service based the application requirements.

    common.doApiCall('api/user', 'GET', function(){

    });

    common.doApiCall('api/user', 'POST', function(){

    });

    common.doApiCall('api/user', 'DELETE', function(){

    });

    common.doApiCall('api/user', 'PUT', function(){

    });

});
```

I want to have something like above but i can't get it right? Can any tell me how to make generic function which used to acces REST API service. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `$http` usage is pretty well explained in the [docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/docs/api/ng.$http#usage). I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: this is already done by angular. Try http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource .

Answer (score 2):

I can see two mistakes in your code:

1) Replace app.factroy by **app.factory**

2) In your controller, you inject your application module and not your service, see :

```
app.factory('APIService', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        doApiCall: function(url, method, payload, headers){

            // I should make a call to server with the parameters passed
            // from the controller.

            var xhr = $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                headers: headers || {}, // Optional headers
            });

            // You probably want to differentiate success / error handlers
            xhr.success(payload);
            xhr.error(payload);

            return xhr;
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'APIService' , function($scope, api) {

    // You should be able to call your service:
    api.doApiCall('api/user', 'DELETE', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the error info. I'm looking for the $http call to the server here. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably a little bit late but I built a generic angular web service api where you can pass in as many parameters as you like:

https://github.com/cullimorer/AngularGenericAPIService